# Bottom Padding doesn't apply to Last-Child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to create a Jumbotron for myself like bootstrap one. I wrote the HTML Codes :

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="title">Rojbas Framework !</div>
    <div>This Roj Framework !</div>
    <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

After that I wanted to apply a Top Padding to First Child & Bottom Padding to Last Child. The First Child works but the Last Child doesn't ...
This is the code :

```
.jumbotron:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 40px;}
```

Comment: should be `.jumbotron :last-child`

Comment: @GCyrillus Thanks ...

Comment: Is there any reason to add padding top bottom to it's childs? Why don't you simply give paddings to *.jumbotron* itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply the padding to the last div in this structure.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="title">Rojbas Framework !</div>
    <div>This Roj Framework !</div>
    <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The selector should be

```
.jumbotron >:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 40px;}
```

Note:

```
.jumbotron :last-child {
    padding-bottom: 40px;}
```

will apply padding to both the last div and **any** last child **however deep** inside the `.jumbotron` element.

Comment: Thanks, It's syntax is like this or It has another reason ?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry, I said last-child is like first-child but It has > sign more ..., It is its syntax or It has a reason to write like this ?

Comment: If you don't use `>` it will apply the bottom padding to every last child...including the button which is also a last child of it's parent, http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048